# The installation of MikTex stops showing a list of options!

Tags: miktex

I had to change my computer with WIn10, where I had TexStudio+MikTex. On the new computer which still uses Win10 I am reinstalling MikTex and TexStudio, but MikTex installer (basic-miktex-22.7-x64.exe) stops showing a list of options "Usage: setupwiz [OPTIONS]". It seems that I should install it manually! Is that right? If so why the manual doesn't mention that? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today too. I guess you installed it system-wide for all users (the option MiKTeX doesn't recommend), right?

The solution: **Run the installer as admin** by right clicking on the installer file and click *run as admin*. Then proceed as normal with the global installation.

---

P.S.: After installation of MiKTeX, it is recommended to make a update for all packages. I don't know if it's a bug, but try not to update the `miktex-doc` package. (At least for me, the MiKTeX consoel halted. After killing the console in Task Manager, some errors with missing `.dll` files popped up every time I tried to start the console again, suggesting that I should reinstall MiKTeX.)

Comment: I got rid of miktex and I installed texlive!

Comment: @nino_user183677 I don't know if this is the correct answer to your problem but certainly an alternative. Is `latexmk` available on texlive? Because the official `latexmk` site mentions MiKTeX for Windows users.

Comment: And it would be nice if someone could verify my solution on his/her system.